# PLSQL Performance Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is more of a doubt than a problem. I have a requirement of just selecting some of the common fields from one table and insert it into a different table. I have done the code with 2 different styles but both with BULK COLLECT. Which is the **better option to go for or is there any other way apart from this**?

Please find the necessary details below.

## Procedure (Way 1):

```
  create or replace procedure a2 is
     cursor c1 is select id,address from emp1;
     type t is table of c1%rowtype;
     c t;
  begin
     open c1;
     loop
        fetch c1 bulk collect into c;
        exit when c.count=0;
        forall j in 1..c.count save exceptions
        insert into empl1(id,address) values (c(j).id,c(j).address);
     end loop;
     commit;
  exception when others then
     for j in 1..sql%bulk_exceptions.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line('The sql error is error occured');
     end loop;
  end a2;
  /
```

Running the above procedure and output:

```
declare
a number;
begin
dbms_output.put_line ('before procedure: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'));
a2;
dbms_output.put_line ('after procedure: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'));
end;
```

## Output :

```
 before procedure: 23:44:48
 after procedure: 23:45:47
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

So the above procedure took 59 seconds to insert 34801020 records.

Now please find the second procedure.

## Procedure (Way 2):

```
create or replace procedure a3 is
   cursor c1 is select id,address from emp1;
   type t is table of c1%rowtype;
   c t;
begin
   select id,address  bulk collect into c from emp1;
   forall j in 1..c.count save exceptions
   insert into empl1(id,address) values (c(j).id,c(j).address);
exception when others then
   for j in 1..sql%bulk_exceptions.count loop
      dbms_output.put_line('The sql error is error occured');
   end loop;
end a3;
 /
```

Running the above procedure with output .

```
declare
a number;
begin
dbms_output.put_line ('before procedure: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'));
a3;
dbms_output.put_line ('after procedure: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'));
end;
```

## Output :

```
before procedure: 23:47:57
after procedure: 23:48:53
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This Procedure took 56 seconds to insert 34801020 records.

## Total records in emp1 table.

```
 SQL> select count(1) from emp1;

   COUNT(1)
   ----------
   34801020
```

## Hence My question :

Which of the above two methods is the best way to insert 3 million records into the table and please suggest me if there is any other better way to do the above process of insertion.

Comment: This type of questions is better asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: 1)  DO NOT YELL.  2)  What is wrong with simple, "insert into emp1 select .. from emp1" ?  Over 3M records, the time difference per record is < 0.08 microseconds.

Comment: If u think CAPS is yelling then u are wrong. Anyways i dont want to argue on that point. We are going to put this procedure in a scheduler such that it runs every one hour once. (The query would change) I cannot add the project code here. If i use insert into select is taking me more than 2 minutes.

Comment: Downvoted for the shouting, will undownvote if you repair. On a platform that supports italics, all-caps is not the best way to indicate emphasis, and it is _less_ readable if you try to emphasise whole sentences anyway.

Comment: @halfer i have edited

Comment: Much better, thank you.

Comment: "Way 1" does not make much sense, the loop is executed only once. There is actually no difference (thus you also get almost the same execution times)

Comment: Please, read https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::p11_question_id:1415454871121 about sql vs loop inserts. "Way 1" is more flexible as you may add LIMIT, Way 2 may raise ORA-04030 if input is too big.

Comment: You know that count(1) gets rewritten to count(*)?

Answer (score 4):

I rans a test using a similar piece of code with a similar dataset size

Using a cursor loop

```
  create or replace procedure a2 is
     cursor c1 is select empno,ename from bigemp;
     type t is table of c1%rowtype;
     c t;
  begin
     open c1;
     loop
        fetch c1 bulk collect into c;
        exit when c.count=0;
        forall j in 1..c.count save exceptions
        insert into bigemp2(empno,ename) values (c(j).empno,c(j).ename);
     end loop;
     commit;
  exception when others then
     for j in 1..sql%bulk_exceptions.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line('The sql error is error occured');
     end loop;
  end a2;


SQL> exec a2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:56.93
```

Doing a regular insert statement, not using a cursor-for loop

```
SQL> insert into bigemp2( empno, ename )
select  empno, ename from bigemp t2


29360128 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:11.30
```

Now do a direct path insert

```
SQL> insert /*+ append */ into bigemp2( empno, ename )
select empno, ename from bigemp t2
;


29360128 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:06.01
```

Add some parallelism

```
SQL> alter session enable parallel dml;

Session altered

SQL> insert /*+ append parallel(2 ) */ into bigemp2( empno, ename )
select /* parallel( t2, 2 ) */ empno, ename from bigemp t2
;

29360128 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:03.52
```

So in summary, just by using the appropriate technique, we can make the process go and order of magnitude faster (about 16x faster)

Comment: I'd just note that "faster" isn't always "better", depends on the requirements and situation.  Writing above the HWM isn't always the better way...

Comment: @tbone You are right that faster is not always better. However "better" was not explicitly defined by the poster; but since the only think we had to measure was elapsed time, I went for that approach. But even for this example, using a simple set-based SQL rather than a cursor-for loop was about 5x fater.

Comment: Nice Explanation. +1 for your answer

Comment: Just out of  curiosity -> wont the append hint be ignored if We have a reference key constraint or Triggers for that corresponding table?